# Date vs DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am working on a program that requires the date of an event to get returned.

I am looking for a `Date`, not a `DateTime`.

Is there a datatype that returns just the date?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

No there isn't. `DateTime` represents some point in time that is composed of a date and a time. However, you can retrieve the date part via the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property (which is another `DateTime` with the time set to `00:00:00`).

And you can retrieve individual date properties via [`Day`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.day.aspx), [`Month`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.month.aspx) and [`Year`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.year.aspx).

**UPDATE**: In .NET 6 the types `DateOnly` and `TimeOnly` [are introduced](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/#introducing-the-dateonly-and-timeonly-types) that represent just a date or just a time.

Comment: Update on this: It's coming in .NET 6. It will be called `DateOnly` and `TimeOnly`. See 
 https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/49036 for reference. It's already available to try if you install .NET 6 preview 4.

Comment: @ronald, are you so kind to make your answer up to date and talk about DateOnly and TimeOnly fields?

Answer (score 26):

I created a simple [Date struct](https://github.com/claycephus/csharp-date) for times when you need a simple date without worrying about time portion, timezones, local vs. utc, etc.

```
Date today = Date.Today;
Date yesterday = Date.Today.AddDays(-1);
Date independenceDay = Date.Parse("2013-07-04");

independenceDay.ToLongString();    // "Thursday, July 4, 2013"
independenceDay.ToShortString();   // "7/4/2013"
independenceDay.ToString();        // "7/4/2013"
independenceDay.ToString("s");     // "2013-07-04"
int july = independenceDay.Month;  // 7
```

https://github.com/claycephus/csharp-date

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately, not in the .Net BCL.  Dates are usually represented as a DateTime object with the time set to midnight.

As you can guess, this means that you have all the attendant timezone issues around it, even though for a Date object you'd want absolutely no timezone handling.

Comment: If you're using a DateTime value as a Date, set the Kind to UTC. No time zone adjustments to deal with.

  DateTime date = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Today, DateTimeKind,Utc);

Comment: Yes, I can speak from experience that using `date` for anything is a bad idea unless you're 100% sure your app will only ever operate in one time zone.  Saving everything as `datetime` gives you the best of both worlds, including most critically, an easy way to avoid timezone nightmares if your server's timezone configs ever change... and starts writing data in ways you didn't anticipate.  `Datetime` can save you there, `date` can't at all, and will become mindbendingly hard to fix if you ever start writing `date` down with the wrong timezone context.

Comment: @KelseyHannan unless of course you are dealing with things like "date of birth", or "date of purchase", where you explicitly don't want things mysteriously changing days just because you moved countries.  Like say, processing Irish mortgage applications in New Zealand as a non-random example.

Answer (score 9):

Create a wrapper class. Something like this:

```
public class Date:IEquatable<Date>,IEquatable<DateTime>
    {
        public Date(DateTime date)
        {
            value = date.Date;
        }

        public bool Equals(Date other)
        {
            return other != null && value.Equals(other.value);
        }

        public bool Equals(DateTime other)
        {
            return value.Equals(other);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }
        public static implicit operator DateTime(Date date)
        {
            return date.value;
        }
        public static explicit operator Date(DateTime dateTime)
        {
            return new Date(dateTime);
        }

        private DateTime value;
    }
```

And expose whatever of `value` you want.

Comment: I'd suggest that your constructor should set the [DateTime.Kind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind(v=vs.110).aspx) to `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` so that when serialized it gets deserialized without converting (may change date based upon different in timezones).

Comment: @OffHeGoes Set the DateTime.Kind to `DateTimeKind.Utc`. *Do not* set it to `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` because that will guarantee it gets serialized/deserialized with an included time zone offset! A calendar date is the same regardless of time zone, so don't let the system adjust it.

Answer (score 5):

The Date type is just an alias of the DateTime type used by VB.NET (like int becomes Integer). Both of these types have a Date property that returns you the object with the time part set to 00:00:00.

Comment: True. [MSDN doc page for VB.NET Date type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e.aspx) says: *The corresponding type in the .NET Framework is the [System.DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) structure.*

Answer (score 4):

DateTime has a [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property that you can use to isolate the date part.  The [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tostring.aspx) method also does a good job of only displaying the Date part when the time part is empty.

Answer (score 3):

The DateTime object has a Property which returns only the date portion of the value.

```
    public static void Main()
{
    System.DateTime _Now = DateAndTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine("The Date and Time is " + _Now);
    //will return the date and time
    Console.WriteLine("The Date Only is " + _Now.Date);
    //will return only the date
    Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The Date returns a `DateTime` with the time set to 0:00:00

Answer (score 3):

There is no `Date` DataType.

However you can use `DateTime.Date` to get just the Date.

**E.G.**

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

Comment: There is a Date structure, and objects may be declared as type Date.

Comment: @KalebAnderson not in the default implementation .NET, there isn't. If you are talking about the VB.net Date, that is still a DateTime.

Comment: `DateTime.Now.Date` is the same as `DateTime.Today`. There is a `DateTime.UtcNow` that returns the date-time value as universal time (UTC), but there is no UTC equivalent method or property for Today; `DateTimeKind.UtcNow.Date` is the appropriate expression.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that .NET 6 is finally introducing a date only type. It will be called `DateOnly` and there will also be a `TimeOnly` type added to the BCL in the `System` namespace.

It is already available in preview 4. Read [this blog article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/) for further details.

Answer (score 2):

You can return DateTime where the time portion is 00:00:00 and just ignore it. The dates are handled as timestamp integers so it makes sense to combine the date with the time as that is present in the integer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

For this, you need to use the date, but ignore the time value.

Ordinarily a date would be a DateTime with time of `00:00:00`

The `DateTime` type has a `.Date` property which returns the `DateTime` with the time value set as above.

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of the following:

```
DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

But there is no "Date" type in the BCL.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AsOfdates
{
    public string DisplayDate { get; set; }
    private DateTime TheDate;
    public DateTime DateValue 
    {
        get 
        { 
            return TheDate.Date; 
        } 

        set 
        { 
            TheDate = value; 
        } 
    }    
}
```

Comment: Putting some explanation to your answer would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Dejan and Jonas Lomholdt,

`.Net 6` has the `DateOnly` type, it is a structure that is intended to represent only a date like a year, month, and day.

```
DateOnly d1 = new DateOnly(2022, 5, 16);
Console.WriteLine(d1);            // 5/16/2022
Console.WriteLine(d1.Year);      // 2021
Console.WriteLine(d1.Month);     // 5
Console.WriteLine(d1.Day);       // 16
Console.WriteLine(d1.DayOfWeek); // Monday



// Manipulation
DateOnly d2 = d1.AddMonths(3);  // You can add days, months, or years. Use negative values to subtract. We are adding 3 months
Console.WriteLine(d2);     // "8/16/2022"  notice there is NO time

// You can use the DayNumber property to find out how many days are between two dates
int days = d2.DayNumber - d1.DayNumber;
Console.WriteLine($"There are {days} days between {d1} and {d2}");  //There are 92 days between 5/16/2022 and 8/16/2022
```

Full credit goes to Matt Johnson-Pint for this article:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/