# Date object vs. DateTime object

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am currently looking at the msdn pages for the date and datetime object. I also have reflector opened up, and it looks like the date and datetime object just reference the **Date** structure.
Why do we have two objects which reference the same structure? what is the differences between them?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Date vs DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/q/798121/102112)

Comment: Can you clarify which `Date` struct you're referring to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CLR classes (e.g. `DateTime`, `Int32`, etc.)  contain the actual implementation. This is what you will see in Reflector.

Due to their heritage, C# and VB define certain *aliases* for commonly used data types. For example, `int` in C# is an alias of `Int32`. In VB, one such alias is `Date` for `DateTime`.

Here are lists of these aliases:

- [Built-In Types Table (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx)
- [Data Type Summary (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx)

Comment: I think it's weird that there is no `date` or `dateTime` alias for `System.DateTime` in C#.

Comment: The VB implementation is still a hot mess. I recently hit an issue where two dates, which when converted to a posix timestamp are the same and they print the same but the interpreter thinks they are different. Event VBs builtin `objectsAreEqual` fails.

Comment: @TimothyC.Quinn: Well, posix timestamps are "the number of **full seconds** since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC", whereas .net's DateTime has a much finer resolution. So, for example today 12:30:00.100 and 12:30:00.200 would be distinct DateTimes, but both get mapped to the same posix timestamp.

Comment: @TimothyC.Quinn: ...and the default string representation of DateTimes does not include milliseconds, so you won't see the difference unless you use a different format string. I've prepared a small code example to illustrate the issue: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rjozcI

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Date` type.  There is only a [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) type which is what you should use for any date or datetime data.

Comment: As of .NET 4, DateTimeOffset is the recommended way to represent date/time information. DateTime is essentially deprecated.

Comment: @MattDavey: [citation needed] :)

Comment: @Andew Hare why of course :) > *"ADateTimeOffset is the new preferred type to use for the most common date time scenarios."* - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/06/14/datetimeoffset-a-new-datetime-structure-in-net-3-5-justin-van-patten.aspx

Comment: @MattDavey - Very cool :) I don't think that *all* uses of DateTime should be switched over to DateTimeOffset though, just for some cases. Check out the "Usage Guidance" at the bottom of the article.

Comment: yeah my claims as to the deprecation of DateTime were slightly over zealous, there is still a place for it :) I think the reason DateTimeOffset hasn't been widely adopted yet is its slightly confusing name.. people tend to assume it represents an offset to a DateTime (a lot like TimeSpan), whereas it actually represents [date + time + offset].