# extract the date part from DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, comparison

The line of code `DateTime d = DateTime.Today;` results in `10/12/2011 12:00:00 AM`. How can I get only the date part.I need to ignore the time part when I compare two dates.

Comment: Today should also give a 0:00:00 result.

Comment: @digem : Do you mean that midnight is _shown_ as 12AM? Could be. I don't think Today would actually return a culture-dependent value.

Comment: @Henk: in english cultures Today.ToString() returns that value ;)

Comment: @Henk: yes sorry, I was inaccurate. Actually the ToString() returns that value if you use for example en-US culture. It's just because "12.00 AM" is equal to the "00.00" in 24h format ;) (I know it seems strange for non-english people, I'm italian...)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

`DateTime` is a DataType which is used to store both `Date` and `Time`. But it provides Properties to get the `Date` Part.

You can get the Date part from `Date` Property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 6, 1, 7, 47, 0);
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString());

// Get date-only portion of date, without its time.
DateTime dateOnly = date1.Date;
// Display date using short date string.
Console.WriteLine(dateOnly.ToString("d"));
// Display date using 24-hour clock.
Console.WriteLine(dateOnly.ToString("g"));
Console.WriteLine(dateOnly.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"));   
// The example displays the following output to the console:
//       6/1/2008 7:47:00 AM
//       6/1/2008
//       6/1/2008 12:00 AM
//       06/01/2008 00:00
```

Comment: var object = DateTime.Now; object.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39316624/2218697) is **another solution** using `String.Format`, hope helps someone.

Answer (score 33):

There is no way to "discard" the time component.

`DateTime.Today` is the same as:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

If you only want to *display* only the date portion, simply do that - use `ToString` with the format string you need.

For example, using the [standard format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) "D" (long date format specifier):

```
d.ToString("D");
```

Comment: +1: Sometimes the answer is just a `.` away

Comment: @Oded. No. It returns the same. `10/12/2011 12:00:00 AM`.

Comment: @Rauf - You can't get rid of that portion. You can choose not to display it though.

Answer (score 16):

When comparing only the date of the datatimes, use the Date property. So this should work fine for you

```
datetime1.Date == datetime2.Date
```

Comment: this is the best answer.

Comment: +1, this is relevant for `comparing` dates. other answers are for displaying them

Answer (score 13):

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Today.Date;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToShortDateString()); // outputs just date
```

if you want to compare dates, ignoring the time part, make an use of `DateTime.Year` and `DateTime.DayOfYear` properties.

code snippet

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Today;
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(3);
if (d1.Year < d2.Year)
    Console.WriteLine("d1 < d2");
else
    if (d1.DayOfYear < d2.DayOfYear)
        Console.WriteLine("d1 < d2");
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use a formatstring

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;              
String format = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy";     
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString(format));
```