# Display only the Date in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [extract the date part from DateTime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740458/extract-the-date-part-from-datetime-in-c-sharp)

I have this code that display the date.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date1,"ddMMyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

And it gives me an output of 
6/12/2012 12:00:00 AM.

But what I need to display is the date only, how can I remove the time so that the only one to be display is the date?

Comment: so where's your code that outputs the date?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740458/extract-the-date-part-from-datetime-in-c-sharp

Comment: dont forget to mark it as accepted if you got the info you want....

Answer (score 4):

Use the method ToShortDateString() of DateTime

```
dt.ToShortDateString();
```

[See here for refs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx)

> The string returned by the ToShortDateString method is
>   culture-sensitive. It reflects the pattern defined by the current
>   culture's DateTimeFormatInfo object.

Answer (score 2):

This one is what you need

```
String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", dt);    // "3/9/2008"
```

See more here :[string-format-datetime](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Answer (score 0):

The patterns for `DateTime.ToString ('d')` :

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date1,"ddMMyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

// Get date-only portion of date, without its time.
DateTime dateOnly = dt.Date;
// Display date using short date string.
Console.WriteLine(dateOnly.ToString("d"));
```

Also check out : [DateTime.ToString() Patterns](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)