# Datetime Format to Date

Tags: c#

How to convert this?

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

I need to display only date.

Please could any one help to convert this to **Date** only

Comment: You want to convert what to what? o.O Are you looking [`DateTime.Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property? I have no idea what you talking about.

Comment: -1. Have you even google'd this? We are left making massive assumptions unless you provide more context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove time portion of date in C# in DateTime object only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740458/extract-the-date-part-from-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to display only date.

[The `DateTime` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) has numerous ways to accomplish this, most commonly `.ToShortDateString()` and `.ToLongDateString()`:

```
var displayDate = Date.ToShortDateString();
```

For further customizations, you can supply [a formatting string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) to [the `.ToString()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

By 'display' I assume you mean to the console. Based on this assumption:

`Console.WriteLine(Date.Date);`

or

`Console.WriteLine(Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));` (as an example; there are many other strings you can pass into this overload).

More on the available strings here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DateTime` format string

eg,

```
Console.WriteLine(Date.ToShortDateString());
Console.WriteLine(Date.ToString("d"));
Console.WriteLine(Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
```

See,

DateTime Format Methods - http://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/system.datetime_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Standard DateTime Format Strings -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Custom DateTime Format Strings -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

A DateTime always contains the Date and the Time - but you can just output the Datepart of it by using .ToString("d") as mentioned here: [Extract the date part from datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740458/extract-the-date-part-from-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

This will get the date with the time being 00:00:00
    public DateTime date { get { return this.date; } set; }

but as stated in a previous answer to display a datetime with only the date you should check out datetime.tostring formats.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx