# DateTime.Date get me Date and 12:00 AM

Tags: c#, datetime

I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740458/extract-the-date-part-from-datetime-in-c-sharp).

I am going to get **only Date from a DateTime variable** and in this way I used this code:

```
DateTime Start = GetaDateTime();
String Day = Start.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime(Day);
```

But when I use `d.Date` it gives me `'2014-08-23 12:00 AM'`

Actually I should not get `12:00AM` any more????

Comment: `Date` returns a `DateTime`. It has 12:00AM because that is the default for the Time portion. There is no built-in `Date` data type in c#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Actually I should not get 12:00AM any more????

Why not? A `DateTime` has no notion of whether it's meant to be a date or a date and time, or any sort of string formatting. It's just a point in time (and not even quite that, given the odd `Kind` part of it).

Note that a simpler way of getting a `DateTime` which is the same as another but at midnight is just to use `Date` to start with:

```
DateTime start = Foo();
DateTime date = start.Date;
```

No need for formatting and then parsing.

There's no .NET type representing *just* a date. For that, you'll want something like my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project, which has a rather richer set of date/time types to play with.