# To Get Date From DateTime Variable

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I have a variable `testDate` which contains value `{01/02/2016 AM 12:00:00}`. I need to get only date part from the set. For that I used below code:

```
var testDate = startDate.AddDays(i);
var testDateOnly = testDate.Date;
```

But it returns the same `{01/02/2016 AM 12:00:00}`.

Comment: That's because the .NET `DateTime` datatype *always* has a time component...... there's no `Date` datatype with just the date

Comment: Checkout this msdn link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Duplicate question Please follow [extract the date part from DateTime in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740458/extract-the-date-part-from-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove time portion of date in C# in DateTime object only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121271/how-to-remove-time-portion-of-date-in-c-sharp-in-datetime-object-only)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date variable will contain the date, the time part will be 00:00:00

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx

```
// The date with time component
var testDate = startDate.AddDays(i);

// Get date-only portion of date, without its time (ie, time 00:00:00).
var testDateOnly = testDate.Date;

// Display date using short date string.
Console.WriteLine(testDateOnly.ToString("d"));

// OUTPUT will be     1/2/2016
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var testDate = startDate.AddDays(i);
  string dateOnlyString = testDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyy");
```

`"dd-MM-yyy"` this will be the Date Format of the output string, You can choose the format as per your requirements.
You can use the following also for formatting:

```
  dateOnlyString = d.ToString("M/d/yyyy");              // "3/9/2008"
  dateOnlyString = d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy}");           // "03/09/2008"

  // day/month names
  dateOnlyString = d.ToString("ddd, MMM d, yyyy}");    // "Sun, Mar 9, 2008"
  dateOnlyString = d.ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}");  // "Sunday, March 9,2008"

  // two/four digit year
  dateOnlyString = d.ToString("MM/dd/yy}");           // "03/09/08"
  dateOnlyString = d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy}");         // "03/09/2008"
```

Comment: mm will return Minutes not Month!!

Comment: @SmitPatel : Yes you are correct thank you., and take a look into the updates

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the Date in to `String` type using this,

```
var testDate = startDate.AddDays(i);

var testDateOnly = testDate.Date.ToShortDateString(); //string
```

or

```
var testDateOnly = testDate.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

or

```
var testDateOnly = testDate.Date.ToString("d");
```

**Check it [here](http://ideone.com/7orxw4).**
**Find the more about [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)**

**You will get the dd-MM-yyyy format by doing this.**