# Display only the Date format in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql

In my sql  i'm using date(Data type). Then in my Form_load:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from incomes", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
{
int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item[0].ToString();
dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item[1].ToString();
dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item[2].ToString();
dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item[3].ToString();
dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item[4].ToString();
```

But in the datagridview column doesnt show only date it shows date with time.
How can i change it, only to date?

Comment: `item[0].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [extract the date part from DateTime in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740458/extract-the-date-part-from-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Error: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: @user6301152 You need to case it to a date time first. For example, `((DateTime)item[0]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitly parse your Date using the [`DateTime.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Convert.ToDateTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime(v=vs.110).aspx) methods and then use the [`ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) method to format it:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(item[0]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

You can use any of the available [standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) or [custom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) formatting strings to output as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, declare it like this:

```
 dataGridView1.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
 this.date.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridView1;
```

or, set it from the designer [Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95y5fz2x.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VS.CELLSTYLEDIALOG%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22%29&rd=true)