# Get only the Date without Time from DateTime

Tags: c#

i came across a situation that, i need to get only the `Date` out from `DateTime`.

i am having a `DateTime? StartDate` property (`Nullable`) used to hold the date value

i tried below,

`var d = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate).Date;`

but its returning me d as eg. `6/22/2006 12:00:00AM`

after doing `var d = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate).Date.ToString("d");`

i'm able to get d as `6/22/2006`..but i dont want to convert my `DateTime?` to `String`

is their any way to get only the `Date` without using the `ToString("d")`?

Comment: A `DateTime` has always a time component, even the `Date`-property returns a `Date` with a time set to 12:00:00 midnight. So no, there is no way to get a `Date`-only without converting it to string. But why are you missing it?

Comment: Instead of `Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate).Date`, use `StartDate.Value.Date`. Both will throw an exception if the `StartDate` is null, so you should make sure it is not.

Comment: Can you explain why this is actually a problem? Is there any specific reason why you can't just use a `DateTime` and simply ignore the time-part?

Answer (score 33):

Use the **Date** property to get the Date component of DateTime instance:

```
DateTime dateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
DateTime datePartOnly = dateTimeNow.Date;    // Return 00/00/0000 00:00:00
```

With this approach, Date property will return the date at midnight. So the time part will be `00:00:00` in this case.

There are couple of alternate ways to get the just the Date part, but the return type of it will be a string:

1.) Using `.ToString(string? format)` where `format` can be standard or custom format string

```
string dateOnlyString = dateTimeNow.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
//Can also use .ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

2.) Using `.ToShortDateString()` to return a culture sensitive date string

```
string dateOnlyString = dateTimeNow.ToShortDateString(); 
//Returns M/d/yyyy for "en-US" culture
//Returns yyyy/M/d for "ja-JP" culture
```

Reference: [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121271/how-to-remove-time-portion-of-date-in-c-sharp-in-datetime-object-only?rq=1)

Comment: Does also return `3/11/2014 12:00:00 AM` what OP doesn't want. He  wants a `DateTime` without a time component.

Comment: Of course, but you should mention that in your answer. `Date` is not the answer to OP's question (he even used `Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate).Date`).

Comment: He already used the `Date` property, so an answer simply asking him to use the `Date` property is uesless.

Answer (score 16):

try this:
`string x = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()`.

this will get the date dd/mm/yy given to the string x.

Comment: It doesnt seem to exist in xamarin forms. Although on msdn it is suggested under system namespace.

Answer (score 3):

In [C# 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10?ranMID=46131&ranEAID=a1LgFw09t88&ranSiteID=a1LgFw09t88-NhYtU9N1CtcRDImZdW4tZw&epi=a1LgFw09t88-NhYtU9N1CtcRDImZdW4tZw&irgwc=1&OCID=AID2200057_aff_7806_1243925&tduid=%28ir__cl20z3o2j9kfq3zbkk0sohz31m2xozb2s63cobiu00%29%287806%29%281243925%29%28a1LgFw09t88-NhYtU9N1CtcRDImZdW4tZw%29%28%29&irclickid=_cl20z3o2j9kfq3zbkk0sohz31m2xozb2s63cobiu00) you can use [DateOnly](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/using-dateonly-and-timeonly-in-dotnet-6).

```
DateOnly date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you question is sort of... moot.

You ask for a date without a time, but get a `DateTime`, which has both. I really don't think that should be a problem in most cases though:

If you create a `DateTime` with a certain date, and compare it to another date, and both of these have their time set to midnight, your comparisons will be valid and correct. Eg:

```
var yesterday = new DateTime(2014, 3, 10);
var today = new DateTime(2014, 3, 11);
var tomorrow = new DateTime(2014, 3, 12);
```

Comparing and sorting these will work as you expect, and so will the following:

```
if(today == DateTime.Today){
    Console.WriteLine("Today is the day!");
}
```

In other words, you should be perfectly fine just *pretending like the time-part does not exist*.

Also, as you touched upon yourself in the OP, you can use the property `Date` if you want to make sure to avoid any time-component:

```
// Note the addition of hours, minutes and seconds:
var today = new DateTime(2014, 3, 11, 14, 35, 33); 

if(today == DateTime.Today){
    Console.WriteLine("This never happened...");    
}

if(today.Date == DateTime.Today){
    Console.WriteLine("...But today is still the day!");    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A `DateTime` does have both a date and a time. You can decide with yourself that in a specific property you well never use the date part. It will just be `12:00 AM`, but you won't use it.

In some situations it can be useful to write your own type that can never hold a time-of-day component. Here is a start:

```
struct Date : IFormattable
{
    readonly DateTime value;
    public Date(DateTime dateAndTime)
    {
        value = dateAndTime.Date;
    }

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        return value.ToString(format ?? "d", formatProvider);
    }
    public string ToString(string format)
    {
        return ToString(format, null);
    }
    public string ToString(IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        return ToString(null, formatProvider);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToString(null, null);
    }

    public static implicit operator DateTime(Date date)
    {
        return date.value;
    }
}
```

The field `value` does hold the 12 AM thing, but it is `private` and is not seen from the outside. The overloads of `ToString()` make sure that unless something else is requested, the `Date` is written out with the short date format of the current culture.