# DateTime should change to date in dataset

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Dataset value Convert `DateTime` to `Date`

```
   foreach (DataRow dr in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
   {
      dr["JoinDate"] = DateTime.Parse((dr["JoinDate"].ToString())).ToShortDateString();
      dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["JoinDate"] = dr["JoinDate"];
   }
```

Comment: Add few lines of your questions too. We cant predict what you want from your question. :)

Comment: its very unclear , can you edit and repost?

Answer (score 0):

**I assume that you want to get the Date part alone form Datetime from your question (datetime is should change to only date in dataset)**

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                dr["JoinDate"] = DateTime.Parse((dr["JoinDate"].ToString())).Date
                dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["JoinDate"] = dr["JoinDate"];
            }
```

**Datetime.Date**  will give you the date value.

refer this : [How to remove time portion of date in C# in DateTime object only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121271/how-to-remove-time-portion-of-date-in-c-sharp-in-datetime-object-only)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
  dr["JoinDate"] = dr["JoinDate"].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
  dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["JoinDate"] = dr["JoinDate"];
}
```