# C# Data type for Birthdate

Tags: c#, date, types

There is no Date type.  If I want an object that is only a date with no time, like a birthdate, what type would I use?

I'm sure this question has been asked and answered already, but I'm not finding this exact question, only lots about date and datetime in general.

Thanks!

(**Edit:** I am not asking how to remove the date, or the time, from a DateTime. I was hoping that there might be a data type that stores ONLY date, and not a date and a time together.  The answer, it seems, is No.)

Comment: Well, it's obvious that you only want the `date` part of a `datetime` so I suggest you use the [Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property of the [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) struct. For more info, see this dupe link: [How to remove time portion of date in C# in DateTime object only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121271)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no just `Date` type, use the `DateTime` data type and only set the date, the time will be all 0s.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston - you could make your own `Date` struct if you really want one.

Comment: you *could*, yes.  and then you could write all of the infrastructure around `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset`, and handle all the calendars and daylight savings, etc.  but why would you, when someone's already done all that work?

Answer (score 1):

There not is an only Date type... Use Date type, and set only the date, and to get only the date use ex: DateTime.Now.Date