# How do I output just the date in a console application?

Tags: c#, datetime, console-application

```
BirthDate = new DateTime(2015,12,30, 00, 0, 0);
// and Tried this too
//BirthDate = new DateTime(2015,12,30);
Console.WriteLine(BirthDate);
```

The result is this:

> 12/30/2015 12:00:00 AM

What I want to achieve is:

> 12/30/2015 00:00:00

or:

> 12/30/2015

Is there any way I could do this in the console app using the `DateTime`?

**[EDIT]**

> I know how to Format Strings in `Console.WriteLine` method or manipulate the strings. What i
>   asked here was whether there is a method in `DateTime` class to do
>   this.

Comment: Let, DateTime expert, Jon Skeet handle this question ;)

Comment: Do you mean `BirthDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`? @Neel you don't need to be a genius to figure out some date formatting string.

Comment: Dates do not have formats. Are you asking how to *display* the date in a specific way?

Comment: Agree! but It was instant reaction while I saw datetime tag before even reading the question @CodeCaster

Comment: what's wrong with this code?!

Comment: How come no-one remembered that `Console.WriteLine` accepts a format string?

Comment: Is this _really_ duplicate? None of answers in duplicate link answers this question as far as I can see.. or.. I need more coffee to wake up.

Comment: @SonerGönül not duplicate of *that* question but I'm certain there are at least 5 other questions that ask how to output a date in a certain way

Comment: `12:00:00 AM` is the same as `00:00:00`, only displayed in a different culture. Compare `Console.WriteLine(BirthDate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));` to `Console.WriteLine(BirthDate.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")));` -- When displaying a `DateTime` it's best (read: most unambiguous) to always specify a format and a formatProvider (i.e. a CultureInfo). So try: `BirthDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

Comment: @Corak in this case the only culture-sensitive part is the separator, all others are numbers. In Germany the separator used to be `.` (I think)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - the char `'/'` is the global date separator (at least by default?). So `new DateTime(2015, 12, 30).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"))` will produce `"12.30.2015"` and a lot of strange looks from germans (we use the "proper" format: `dd.MM.yyyy`). -- joking aside, `yyyy-MM-dd` is the only true format and should be used everywhere instead of everything else.

Comment: @Soner what about the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6124299/266143) to the one I closed this as a duplicate of? The core question here is _"How to format a date"_, which is answered there. I hope you don't mean _"But the format here is `MM/dd/yyyy`, while in that answer it is `dd/MM/yyyy`"_, we don't go create a question per date format. I find the one I linked better than the one currently linked, because the latter doesn't even mention dates. _"How to format strings in Console.WriteLine"_ is a different question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I reopened the question and posted my answer which I try to explain a little bit more why OP get this result at the first time and how to get the other formats that he wants. After that, I closed it again if you don't mind.

Comment: We already have hundreds, if not thousands of questions about formatting dates. Getting a bit tired of the repetition.

Comment: @SonerGönül not at all - just wish I could find the *right* duplicate for date related questions easily so I don't have to search each time!

Comment: @CodeCaster You have a point. I wasn't look the second answer, and honestly, your duplicate question is not even clear in my opinion. It says; _I can not use any string conversion methods as I need the date in object form_ and I'm like o.O? What is that _date in object form_ exactly? Does he wanna get a DateTime without Time part (which is not possible as we all know) or does he wanna get only only date part with midnight time part (which is `.Date` property for) or does he wanna get a string representation which includes only date part? But of course, as you said, we should close...

Comment: @CodeCaster all of these questions as a duplicate as "_How to format a date?_" one which we have thousands (maybe millions in future) of questions like that..

Comment: @Soner, Panagiotis because of all this duplication, the Google query "C# print format date only datetime site:stackoverflow.com" yields 36.000 (!) results. Subtract some duplication because of tag pages and we easily have 20.000 questions about date formatting, which is extremely sad. We need a very good, canonical date formatting question that explains what a DateTime is and how to get only the parts you're interested out of it in the desired format, but I'm afraid it already exists but is unfindable.

Comment: @CodeCaster Amen to that. Maybe because one of the reason that people can't find the right link in Google search can be there are too many variation of a DateTime formatting.

Comment: I know how to Format Strings in Console.WriteLine method or manipulate the strings. What i asked here was whether there is a method in DateTime class to do this.

Comment: @aimme I think that was answered in this answer already, multiple times. In fact, it's the same thing as WriteLine - use the proper format string either in `ToString` or with String.Format, WriteLine etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Console.WriteLine(BirthDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

As mentioned by Panagiotis Kanavos in comments, you can format it as well in this way

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", BirthDate);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are *already* right answers here but let me try to explain a little bit deeper..

Since there is no `Console.WriteLine(DateTime)` overload, your code will call `Console.WriteLine(object)` overload and for `DateTime` type, this method will generate [`G` standard format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#GeneralDateLongTime) representation of your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

That means the combination of your [`ShortDatePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`LongTimePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longtimepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) properties is `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` of your `CurrentCulture`.

And from this result you get, your `CurrentCulture` has `/` as a [`DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) and `:` as a [`TimeSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is great for the results you want. You will not need to use another `IFormatProvider` to generate exact results because of these separators.

Just format your value with [custom date and time format specifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", BirthDate); // 12/30/2015 00:00:00
Console.WriteLine("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", BirthDate); // 12/30/2015
```

or use `DateTime.ToString()` method which is equal;

```
Console.WriteLine(BirthDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")); // 12/30/2015 00:00:00
Console.WriteLine(BirthDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");// 12/30/2015
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the date property, for example:

```
var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
var date = dateAndTime.Date;
```

The date variable will contain the date, then the time will show 00:00:00..

Answer (score 0):

Converts the value of the current DateTime object to its equivalent string representation using the specified format and the formatting conventions of the current culture.

```
Console.WriteLine(BirthDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu thanks.. I agree with you... updated

Answer (score 0):

You may refer Standard Date and Time Format Strings for vast options. [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx).

And for your requirement, you may do something like the example below. (which were mentioned already by others in this thread)

```
BirthDate = new DateTime(2015,12,30, 0, 0, 0);
// and Tried this too
//BirthDate = new DateTime(2015,12,30);
// 12/30/2015 00:00:00
Console.WriteLine(BirthDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
// or
// 12/30/2015
Console.WriteLine(BirthDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Comment: How is this different than the other answers?

Comment: I'm presenting the date time base on my preferred string format. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Again, how is this different that the *other* questions that *also* contain `Console.WriteLine(BirthDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));` ?

Comment: Sorry, haven't seen X-Tech's answer until now.

Answer (score -1):

```
     var datetime = BirthDate.Date.ToShortDateString();
     Console.WriteLine(datetime);
```

Comment: the time value of BirthDate is already 00:00:00 when you set `BirthDate = new DateTime(2015,12,30, 00, 0, 0);` there is no need to use another variable

Comment: `BirthDate.Date` is enough,

Comment: X-TECH who said that BirthDate.Date is enough.check the code then down vote me!!I have tested the code

Comment: This won't work in non-US locales, or even in the US if the user changes the system's short date pattern. Moreover, the short date string doesn't include a time component so even the call to `.Date` has no effect.

Answer (score -1):

Another way of doing this without the hard coding of format strings would be:

```
    var currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    var shortDatePattern = currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today.ToString(shortDatePattern));
```

Comment: The short date pattern is locale *and* user-specific. If you don't want to specify the format exactly, you should specify the short date pattern *and* the corresponding culture, ie en-US in this case

Comment: So, like this?      `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today.ToString(shortDatePattern, currentCulture));`