# Remove time from time and date

Tags: c#

I have a variable `openDate` which holds date and time, and I would like to strip just the date. I tried the below example and it is not working. What am  I doing wrong, or rather how should I do it because the variable `openDate` remains the same even after trying to strip just the date? The value of `openDate` is "2012-03-08 00:00:00"

```
openDate = ! string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.ChildNodes[f].Attributes["ows_PMO_x0020_Origination_x0020_Date"].Value)
           ? node.ChildNodes[f].Attributes["ows_PMO_x0020_Origination_x0020_Date"].Value
           : "" ;
openDate  = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", openDate);
```

Comment: Or you can just use `openDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove time portion of date in C# in DateTime object only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121271/how-to-remove-time-portion-of-date-in-c-sharp-in-datetime-object-only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your date into a `DateTime` object first. See examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx) if your string is in a different or custom format.

```
openDate = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.ChildNodes[f].Attributes["ows_PMO_x0020_Origination_x0020_Date"].Value)? node.ChildNodes[f].Attributes["ows_PMO_x0020_Origination_x0020_Date"].Value: "" ;
//openDate is a string at this point. You'll need to convert it to a datetime object first, for the following line to work:
var dtObject = DateTime.Parse(openDate);
//Format the newly created datetime object
openDate  = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dtObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

considering `openDate` is of a String type, i would do this

`var dt = DateTime.Parse(openDate).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");`

Answer (score 1):

From your code it is clear that `openDate` is of type string and you have value that is a string representation of `DateTime`, you can apply `DateTime` formatting on string values.

You have multiple options.

- Convert `string` `openDate` to a `DateTime` value and then apply formatting
- Do some string operations to extract the date part from your string value.

String operations:

```
string openDate = "2012-03-08 00:00:00";
string formatted = openDate.Substring(0, openDate.IndexOf(' '));
```

`DateTime` Parsing.

```
DateTime parsedDateTime = DateTime.Parse(openDate);
string formattedDateTime = parsedDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format datetime using:
If it is a datetime:

```
OpenDate = OpenDate.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

If the datatype is not datetime and you are sure the format will always be that then you can always convcert the string to datetime and use the method described above.

```
Convert.ToDateTime(openDate).ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

Comment: `openDate` is a string in this case, and it would not work here.

Answer (score 0):

The answers are great, especially if you would like to control the format of your 'time' part. Here is teh simplest way to get what you are after:

```
        var dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2012-03-08 00:00:04");

        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToLongTimeString());
        Console.WriteLine(dt.TimeOfDay);
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use the following -  `openDate = openDate.Date`

Comment: `openDate` is a string in this case, and it would not work here.