# How to remove Time in DateTime

Tags: c#, date, datetime

Hello I know this is a duplicate question however I want to remove the `Time` in `DateTime` format.

For example I have this `DateTime` value `8/3/2016 12:00:00 AM`. I want to remove the `Time 12:00:00 AM` and use the remaining value.

I tried this one

`DateTime DATE= Convert.ToDateTime(DATE);`

`var date2 = DATE.date;` but it only take the date not the whole value.

Comment: The duplicate question will have your answer.

Comment: If you know this is a duplicate question, then why are you posting it again instead of using the answer to one of the others?

Comment: @DavidTansey The other answer that I saw is they just get the date only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove time portion of date in C# in DateTime object only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121271/how-to-remove-time-portion-of-date-in-c-sharp-in-datetime-object-only)

Comment: @nhouser9 using the `.Date` it will get the whole value of 8/3/2016? Not the date only?

Comment: @nhouser9 if not then it is different to what I want.

Comment: You're asking how to get the date only, and the linked duplicate shows you how to get the date only. If that's not what you want, [edit] your question to explain what it is you **really** want instead of repeating the same nonsense over and over again in comments.

Comment: @KenWhite in my example I want to get the whole 8/3/2016 and remove the 12:00:00 AM in datetime.

Comment: As I said, [edit] your question to make it clear what you're asking. **Don't say it again in comments, but [edit] your question and say it there instead.**

Comment: @KenWhite no need to **argue** I solve my own problem now.

Comment: I'm not arguing. I'm trying to get you to listen, but you're still not doing so.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

string date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

Comment: I'm not using DateTime.Now because I pass a value for the date into the my `DateTime DATE`

Comment: The question does not ask how to convert a DateTime to a string.

Answer (score -1):

What you ask is not doable in the terms you seek. If you want operations only on the Date parts you should first extract Date parts like this:

```
var dateString = "8/3/2016 12:00:00 AM";
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
```

You can work only with the date part using Day, Month, Year properties and if needed DayOfYear, DayOfWeek properties. If you want to print Date only use:

```
1. Console.WriteLine(date.ToShortDateString()) or
2. Console.WriteLine(date.ToLongDateString()) or
3. Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("d")) // same as ToShortDateString() // or
4. Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("D")) // same as ToLongDateString() // or
5. Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")) or
6. Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("//Other custom formats")
```