# Get Date part of DateTime(ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this property in Model

```
[Display(Name = "День рождения")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public System.DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
```

And write to database value like this via AJAX

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#save').click(function () {
        save();
    });
});
    function save() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            dataType: 'Json',
            data: {
                FIO: $('#FIO').val(),
                Email: $('#Email').val(),
                Salary: $('#Salary').val(),
                Telephone: $('#Telephone').val(),
                English: $('#english').val(),
                City: $('#City').val(),
                Birthday: $('#Birthday').val(),
                id: $('#Interview_Id').val(),


            },
            url: '@Url.Action("WelcomeWriter", "Interwier")',
            success: function (da) {
                if (da.Result === "Success") {

                    window.location.href = da.RedirectUrl;

                } else {

                    alert('Error' + da.Message);
                }
            },
            error: function (da) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    }
```

But my problem is this - it is writing  Date and Time , I only need Date.

How I can fix this?

Comment: Евгений, есть же stackoverflow по русски, можете туда обратиться: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: разница?

тут людей больше @anete.anetes

Comment: окладно. вот решение на сервере: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121271/how-to-remove-time-portion-of-date-in-c-sharp-in-datetime-object-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var date = new Date($('#Birthday').val());
```

This will give you access to all the Date functions.
For example:

```
var day = date.getDate(); 
var month = date.getMonth();  
var year = date.getFullYear()
```

So for full date:

```
var fullDate=day+"/"+month+"/"+year;
```

Or:

```
var fullDate=d.toLocaleDateString();
```

Comment: so in ajax call I need to write like this `data: {
                    FIO: $('#FIO').val(),
                    Email: $('#Email').val(),
                    Salary: $('#Salary').val(),
                    Telephone: $('#Telephone').val(),
                    English: $('#english').val(),
                    City: $('#City').val(),
                    Birthday: fulldate,
                    id: $('#Interview_Id').val(),


                }`?

Comment: @Eugene Yes, like this.

Comment: @Eugene Yes. You need to check what date type is required in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Format your date in your save() method before you do your ajax call. Something like this:

```
var d = new Date($('#Birthday').val());
var birthday = d.getFullYear() + "-" + ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
                + "-" + ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2);
```

Comment: so in ajax call I need to write like this `data: {
                    FIO: $('#FIO').val(),
                    Email: $('#Email').val(),
                    Salary: $('#Salary').val(),
                    Telephone: $('#Telephone').val(),
                    English: $('#english').val(),
                    City: $('#City').val(),
                    Birthday: fulldate,
                    id: $('#Interview_Id').val(),


                }`?

Comment: In my example it would be Birthday: birthday

Comment: Do you still get the error when you remove the birthday from the data payload?

Comment: If I write like before. No

Comment: Do you know in which string format your backend accept the date?