# Select Only the Date part and display

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have a table called Jobs which has several columns, One of the column being ProofDate Column. Now the Column shows the date and as well as time.. I want to display the entire table in a tab of windows form application along with the ProofDate..But The proof Date must show only the Date and not the time..Can anyone help me with it??

Comment: Can you show us your existing code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove time portion of date in C# in DateTime object only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121271/how-to-remove-time-portion-of-date-in-c-sharp-in-datetime-object-only)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select CONVERT(DATE, ColumnName) From Table
```

Would give you just the date of a column which is datetime

Comment: This works..But How can i show the rest of the  columns along with the date in this format?

Comment: Select Column1, Column2, CONVERT(DATE,Column3) From Table

Answer (score 0):

Applications and databases work best when you leave DateTime as complete DateTime objects, and the best time to change that format is when it is time to display the information

Leave the SQL query alone, use one of the [`DateTime.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) methods to just the Date portion. There are plenty of canned methods as well; such as `ToShortDateString()`.

Answer (score -2):

if your `ProofDate` column is `datetime` as datatype then you can use below query.

```
select col1, col2, col3, convert(date,ProofDate ) as colname from table
```

Comment: When this is brought into the C# app this will either became a "full" DateTime again set to midnight. And you don't have a format style in your convert

Comment: yeah it can be done on c# code by using toshortdatestring method @MadMyche

Comment: Yes, the `ToShortDateString()` method will return a string just containing the _Date_ portion of the value. However; if the data type is of the `DateTime` type it will once again be a DateTime value. The string function should only be used on the presentation/ display level