# .Date return also hour, how to remove?

Tags: c#, date

I need to get only the date not the hour from this:

```
DateTime.Parse(tr.SelectSingleNode(".//td[@class='full-date']").InnerText.Trim()).Date;
```

but I get this result:

> 3/24/2018 12:00:00 AM

How can I get only:

> 3/24/2018

Note that I save the result in the following format:

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Comment: Your datetime object is what it says it is `Date` + `Time`... you can't make a datetime object with only a date, it will have time 00:00 (24hrs notation) by default

Comment: I can't set only "Date" object in the property

Comment: ugh, just leave it at 00.00 whats the issue? That way you have whole days

Comment: Have you tried formatting it in your desired format ? Like ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove time portion of date in C# in DateTime object only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121271/how-to-remove-time-portion-of-date-in-c-sharp-in-datetime-object-only)

Comment: and in wpf how can tell to display only date?

Comment: @MarioSerda use `{Binding YourDateTimeProperty, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"`

Comment: @MarioSerda If its about displaying (which has nothing to do with wpf...) use `dateTimeObject.ToString("Mdyyyy");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Note that I save the result in the following format:

you save the result in a variable of type `DateTime` you don't save in in a certain format. Only the string representation of `DateTime` has a format. `DateTime` has always both, date and time ( I guess hence the name ;))

> How can I get only: 3/24/2018 ?

this point becomes important when you try to get the string representation of the `DateTime` using this overload of the [ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
string string_representation = Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove the time component from `System.DateTime`. You could create your own Date representation if you wish. Or, you could get the date string using,

```
Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("MM/dd/yy"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/), which has the concept of a date without time (and vice versa).

To convert from `DateTime` to `LocalDate`:

```
using System;
using NodaTime;

namespace YourApp.Extensions
{
    public static class NodaTimeExtensions
    {
        public static LocalDate ToNodaLocalDate(this DateTime dateTime)
        {
            return new LocalDate(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day);
        }
    }
}
```