# Date format in Substring

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I need help, in assign I have

```vb
out_Date = Split(Question, "Date: ")(1).Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.None)(0)
```

, but in `WriteLine` I have the value of the Date argument as `11 feb 2020 04:54:52- 0500 (EST)`.
How can I set expression only for date like this `02/11/2020`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove time portion of date in C# in DateTime object only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121271/how-to-remove-time-portion-of-date-in-c-sharp-in-datetime-object-only)

Comment: `myDate.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy")`

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear at all.
If I understand correctly, you want to format the date output.

You can use [DateTime Format](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1).