# Removing Time from DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

My sample code for solving this problem:

```cs
    public class Person
    {
        private DateTime _date;
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get { return _date.Date; } set { _date = value; } }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.Name = "AAA";
            p.DateOfBirth = new DateTime(2005,3,2,5,5,5);

            Console.WriteLine(p.DateOfBirth);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

In this case output is:

```
02.03.2005 00:00:00
```

Technically it removed the time, but still returns 00:00:00 as an hour. How can i actually get rid of time? A lot of people post this as solution, but it doesn't really solve the problem.

My expected output is:

```
02.03.2005
```

Comment: Do you want a string representation with out the time or an `DateTime` instance without time?

Comment: [DateTime.Date Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netcore-3.1) and use corresponding [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) to convert to needed string representation.

Comment: you can use ``p.DateOfBirth.ToShortDateString()``

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121271/how-to-remove-time-portion-of-date-in-c-sharp-in-datetime-object-only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to tell it a format specifier;

```cs
Console.WriteLine(p.DateOfBirth.ToString("..."));
```

where `"..."` is your choice; `"d"` maybe (short date). See [standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) and [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) formats.

Answer (score 0):

you need to format the date 
refer https://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

alternatively you can use .ToString() with specified format,

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code

```
Console.WriteLine(p.DateOfBirth.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy"));
```

place `MM` for month
`dd` for day of month as per your convenience