# C# string to Date (yyyy-MM-dd) from DatePicker (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, datepicker

I get a string from my WPF with the date from my DatePicker. The format is: dd / MM / yyyy and the time.
However, I need dd-MM-yyyy or yyyy-MM-dd without a time.
How can I convert it?

Comment: [DateTime.ToShortDateString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?view=net-5.0)

Comment: "*I get a string from my [DatePicker]*" - are you sure? `datePicker.SelectedDate` resolves as `DateTime?`, not as `string`. Once you have a `DateTime`, you can use `.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` for example

Comment: Or if you mean you want to see the date in the textbox you can set the selecteddateformat to short.  The format of that will depend on  the user's settings on their pc  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddateformat?view=net-5.0

Comment: 'dd/MM/yyyy ' sounds like you were reading/Binding the DatePicker.Text Property. This is 
the localized  text representation of the DatePicker.SelectedDate property (wich's type is - according to @Rafalon's comment a DateTime?). Check/Bind the SelectedDate and do ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") as suggested before.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a `DateTime` without a Time in C# without creating some custom classes. You can get the Date portion using the `.Date` property - it will still have the time though (set to midnight).

At most, you can *format* it to not display the time, using ToString with specific formatting, such as `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`.

See this question: [How to remove time portion of date in C# in DateTime object only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121271/how-to-remove-time-portion-of-date-in-c-sharp-in-datetime-object-only)

**Edit**:
If yo use `DateTime?` rather than `DateTime`, this might help:

```
Datum == null ? "IT_IS_NULL" : Datum.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Datum is your variable, replace "IT_IS_NULL" with whatever should be returned for null values.

Comment: `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` doest work for me. I got an Nullable DateTime `public DateTime? Datum { get; set; }`

Comment: You could add a check for null then, and invoke `ToString` on the value. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following is my solution:

```
.AddUrlSegment("datum", Datum?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```