# Convert DateTime.Now to DateOnly in dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: c#

I'm working with a DateOnly variable and I'm trying to get the DateTime.Now time in a dd/mm/yyyy format, however it's only returning the date on mm/dd/yyyy format.

I strictly need the current date in a dd/mm/yyyy format, and I haven't been able to figure it out how to.

This is an example how I'm working to convert the DateTime.Now to DateOnly type

```
public class Example
{
  public DateOnly? Date{get; set;}
}

public class Process1
{
  Example example = new Example();
  {
    example.Date= DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
    //this is returning the current date in a mm/dd/yyyy format
  }
}
```

Comment: `DateOnly` is a binary `struct`, if you want to represent it as a `string` use *formatting*, say `string text = Date.ToString(formatHere);`

Comment: Neither `DateTime` nor `DateOnly` *have* a format. Formatting only comes into play when the value is converted to a string, either explicitly with `.ToString()` or implicitly in one of many ways (because you're viewing it in a debugger, feeding it to `Console.WriteLine`, etc.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# DateTime to "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121271/how-to-remove-time-portion-of-date-in-c-sharp-in-datetime-object-only)

Comment: @AliasgharAhmadpour that answer isn't relevant. `DateTime` and `DateOnly` have no format whatsoever, they're binary values. That answer shows how to format them into *strings* with a specific format. The types themselves store a tick or day offset since 0001-01-01

Comment: Excuse me, i selected wrong link and link edited

Answer (score 18):

Formatting can only be done by string not by date only.

save date in dateonly datatype

```
example.Date= DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
```

but when you need specify format then use string like below

```
string s = example.Date.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
or 
s = example.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

[For More detail refer this Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly.tostring?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

I set the *Date* variable as a DateTime property in the **Example** Class :

`public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;`

In  the main code, i converted the *Date* property into a string and assigned it to *dateOnly* Variable:

`string dateOnly = Convert.ToString(example.Date.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy"));`

Comment: dont need to convert into string twice

Comment: he need format 'dd/mm/yyyy' not 'dd-mm-yyyy'