# How to insert datetime property from asp.net c# to a date column in sql server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a problem using the calender control .. I am getting the date in a textbox... and I have to insert this into the database .. using asp.net with c#

In my web application the field property is set to `datetime` and in the table the column's datatype is `date`..

How can I do this??

The error I am getting is:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.

Could anyone help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to include some info about database schema and the C# you are using to update the database. However it sounds like you are not using the right column types in your database.

Comment: I usually don't work with asp.net web forms, so I need to know: Are you inserting/updating the date yourself, or should the control do that? The issue is probably, as always with dates, regional settings, the format of the date.

Comment: thanks Layoric for your prompt reply actually i have two fileds in my database (sqlserver2008r2) table with the datatype of date now from application(.NET 4) side i want to insert some values in that table but in asp.net C# there is not date datatype i have to use datetime datetype but i am getting this error..i dn't know how to solve this?

Comment: @SteenT the calendar control is inserting date into textbox in my fronend at the backend which i am inserting into table it is not happenning because in my table i have datatype of date and on otherhand in asp.net webforms without datetime there is not alone date datatype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The error i am getting is: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

It sounds like you're trying to insert it as a string, which is a generally bad idea. You should use parameterized SQL and set the value as a parameter, still as a .NET `DateTime`. See the docs for [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) for an example of parameterized SQL. You should always keep data in its natural type for as long as possible.

Of course, it's then *still* possible that you'll get this error if you try to insert a `DateTime` value which is out of the range that SQL can store. In particular, I believe SQL has a lower limit of 1753 as the year. If your value is `DateTime.MinValue` for some reason (January 1st, 1AD) then you'd still get this problem. Have you added diagnostics for the value you're trying to insert?

Comment: I've had issues with DateTime like this as well - my main answer is listed as well.  But I've had issues with both, one problem I had is that DateTime wasn't big enough to handle a FileTime.  So SQL 2008 R2 introduced DateTime2 in SQL.  This fixed my problem (a shallow fix, but it worked); alas, always use parameters if possible like @jon-skeet says.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my first answer missed your question.  Try adding the parameter by doing using the standard parameter system.

command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO FooTable (FooDate) VALUES (@FooDate)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FooDate", DateToUse.Date);

Using the .Date will only return the date part of the object.  Here's another reference to it [Date vs DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798121/date-vs-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a **parametrized query**, I have no trouble whatsoever to insert that `DateTime` from the ASP.NET calendar control into a SQL Server database table that contains a column of type `DATE`.

Use something like this:

```
// define INSERT statement - of course, yours will look quite different!
string insertStmt = "INSERT INTO dbo.DateTest(TheDate) VALUES(@DateValue);";

// set up connection and SqlCommand to do insert
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("....your-connection-string-here...."))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertStmt, conn))
{
     // add the parameters - the @DateValue - to the SqlCommand object and
     // define it's datatype (on the database) and set the value to be stored
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateValue", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Calendar1.SelectedDate;

     // open connection, execute command, close connection
     conn.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try one thing first, try to insert 01/01/2012 in the column, because that could because of wrong culture.... it could be mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy

try this 01/01/2012 first and see if thats working.

thanks