# DateTime in VB.NET and C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datetime, value-type

I have two questions:

1. `Date` and `DateTime` : Are they different or same in VB ?
2. `DateTime` can be assigned Nothing in VB, where as it cannot be assigned null in C#. Being a structure it cannot be null. So why is it being allowed in VB ?

---VB.NET-----

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim d As Date = Nothing
        Dim dt As DateTime = Nothing

        d = CType(MyDate, DateTime)


    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property MyDate As DateTime
        Get
            Return Nothing
        End Get
    End Property

End Module
```

---C#.NET-----

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime dt = null;//compile time error            
        }
    }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798121/date-vs-datetime

Comment: @musefan: ok, but in VB.NET you can write `Dim dt As Date? = Nothing`. So what's the difference?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: The very appropriately named `Dim` is the difference. I know we cool kids have the ever lazy 'var', but my blind hatred for VB doesn't need to be backed up by reason, I just need to ensure I do my part and make the correct noises when ever the chance arises... #CutForVB

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Nothing` in VB.NET is not the same as `null` in C#. It has also the function of `default` in C# and that is what happens when you use it on a structure like `System.DateTime`.

So both, `Date` and `DateTime` refer to the same struct `System.DateTime` and

```
Dim dt As Date = Nothing
```

actually is the same as

```
Dim dt = Date.MinValue
```

or (in C#)

```
DateTime dt = default(DateTime);
```

Comment: i always find it funny when people say 'Why arent these languages identical!' the idea ofc being if they were identical the only difference would end up being the words you use to do it...

Answer (score 3):

In c# You can use `default` keyword

```
DateTime dt = default(DateTime);
```

`Date` and `DateTime` are same in VB.NET. `Date` is just [alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx) of `DateTime`

Answer (score 3):

In vb.net `Date` is simply an [alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx) for `DateTime`.

Some of aliases that exist in VB are there for legacy purposes to help with conversions from vb6 applications.