# SQLite with Powershell - SQLite Datatyp Date is being transferred into DateTime in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, sqlite

I'm connecting to an SQLite Database with the system.data.sqlite.org binaries.

At the end, I'm querying my database with

```
$adapter = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter $sql
$data = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
[void]$adapter.Fill($data)
```

Generally, this is working pretty fine but if you have an SQLite Data type Date its being imported into PowerShell as DateTime which is adding 00:00:00 as timestamp.

Can this be avoided? I would like to have the Date as dd-mm-yyyy in PowerShell without the timestamp. For timestamp fields I want to have the date + timestamp of course, but not for the date data types.

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as a "SQLite Datatype Date". SQLite stores null, integer, real, text or blobs. DateTime values are stored as text or as integers in some format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "Date" datatype in .NET (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/798138/2060966)), only [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netframework-4.8) (or `DateTimeOffset`). Even the [Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netframework-4.8) property on a `DateTime` object will return *another* `DateTime` (with the time component set to 00:00:00).

If you want that particular format, you can format the value as a string:

```
$datetimevalue.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much... Can I get the SQLite Datatype in powershell so I do the ToString only for some data I query?

Comment: I already have it.. you need to query the database with pragma and it returns the datatypes.